# MVC How to return view in ActionFilterAttribute like ActionResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult, actionfilterattribute

Is it even possible to return a view from an ActionFilterAttribute?
Right now i just have it throw an error and in the OnException in the base controller reroutes to an error page. Would liek to show my NoAccess view like i do when theres an permissions problem inside an action, but have it occur from an attribute on the action.

```
    public sealed class UserHasPermissionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
      {
if(HasPermission == false){

//What are my options here a view?

}
}
}
```

Seen several sites an blogs, but none have explained well, or what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of what you're using your action filter for, it sounds like perhaps you should be using the `AuthorizeAttribute`?

Alternatively you could try just redirecting in the OnActionExecuting method itself, using something like:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(errorUrl);
```